# Can the school see what I searched for on TikTok?

Tags: privacy, account-security, search-engines

I was on my laptop at home using my network but I was on my school Google account I searched for TikTok and when I was on TikTok, I used TikTok's search function for some inappropriate things.

I am worried the school will see what I searched for on TikTok, but I am not sure. I deleted it from the search history on my laptop. If anyone knows if I am worrying over nothing or do I need to do something else to erase it.

Comment: No, they cannot see what you do on non-Google websites, even though you started out searching on Google using your Google account.